# NSDictionary not sent via HTTP POST

Tags: ios, objective-c, afnetworking-2

I don't know what i am doing wrong but when i try to send this NSDictionary

```
NSDictionary *payload = [[NSDictionary alloc]
                         initWithObjects:@[
                                           [[self name] text],
                                           [[self dob] text],
                                           [[self phone] text],
                                           [[self email] text],
                                           [[self address] text],
                                           [[self city] text],
                                           [[self state] text],
                                           [[self zipcode] text],
                                           [NSNumber numberWithBool:hi],
                                           [NSNumber numberWithBool:li],
                                           [NSNumber numberWithBool:di],
                                           [NSNumber numberWithBool:hsa],
                                           [NSNumber numberWithBool:client],
                                           [NSNumber numberWithBool:info]
                                           ]
                         forKeys:@[@"name",
                                   @"dob",
                                   @"phone",
                                   @"email",
                                   @"address",
                                   @"city",
                                   @"state",
                                   @"zipcode",
                                   @"hi",
                                   @"li",
                                   @"di",
                                   @"hsa",
                                   @"client",
                                   @"info"]];

if (online) {
    // enviar el post .
```

via POST the server receives nothing, but if i do it via GET then there is no problem.

```
    [afFetch POST:baseURL parameters:payload success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
        if ([[responseObject objectForKey:@"success"] boolValue]) {
            NSLog(@"%@", responseObject);
            [self showSuccessMessage:YES];
        } else {

            [self showSuccessMessage:NO];
        }

    } failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
        NSLog(@"Error: %@",error);
        [self showSuccessMessage:NO];
    }];
```

I guess i am missing something but i am unable to find it. Any ideas ? Thanks

Comment: You may be interested in the `@{key: value, ...}` notation for creating `NSDictionary` objects... it makes your code much more readable.

Comment: Have you tried to send one object only?

Comment: Is your server configured correctly to accept the data via POST?

Comment: @IanMacDonald thanks for the advise let me refactor that . but in theory it should work the same way

Comment: @Stonz2 Yes, in fact if i make the post outside the app works perfectly, that is why i think there might be something wrong with the code

Answer (score 0):

As per @ian-macdonald recommendation I refactored the code with the `@{key: value, ...}` notation and this fixed the issue. Here's the example:

```
NSDictionary *payload = @{@"name":[[self name] text],
                          @"dob":[[self dob] text],
                          @"phone":[[self phone] text],
                          @"email":[[self email] text],
                          @"address":[[self address] text],
                          @"city":[[self city] text],
                          @"state":[[self state] text],
                          @"zipcode":[[self zipcode] text],
                          @"hi":[NSNumber numberWithBool:hi],
                          @"li":[NSNumber numberWithBool:li],
                          @"di":[NSNumber numberWithBool:di],
                          @"hsa":[NSNumber numberWithBool:hsa],
                          @"client":[NSNumber numberWithBool:client],
                          @"info":[NSNumber numberWithBool:info]};
```

Comment: You can further reduce with NSNumber literals.  @"hi": @(hi)    I am confused however at how this fixed the problem you were having.  This is cleaner but the code should be equivalent...

Comment: @KirkSpaziani, i didn't understand neither but the truth  its that it fixed, it might have something to do with an AFNetworking convention  but that is only a guess.